# How to create table rows dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

I'm trying to create a table with rows and columns dynamically from an array.
My rest request is working fine and i have an hard coded example with entries but when changing this to a dynamic approach with loop or map it gets me nuts.

```
return {
    columns: [
      { Header: "Mitglied", accessor: "name", width: "45%", align: "left" },
      { Header: "Rolle", accessor: "function2", align: "left" },
      { Header: "Status", accessor: "status", align: "center" },
      { Header: "Seit", accessor: "employed", align: "center" },
      { Header: "action", accessor: "action", align: "center" },
    ],

    rows: [
      {
        name: <User image={team2} name={users[0].firstName} email="mail@me.com" />,
      },
      {
        name: <User image={team2} name={users[1].firstName} email="mail@me.com" />,
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

But i dont get it running with my loop approach.

```
 return {
    columns: [
      { Header: "Mitglied", accessor: "name", width: "45%", align: "left" },
      { Header: "Rolle", accessor: "function2", align: "left" },
      { Header: "Status", accessor: "status", align: "center" },
      { Header: "Seit", accessor: "employed", align: "center" },
      { Header: "action", accessor: "action", align: "center" },
    ],
    rows:  users.map((user) => ({
        name: <User image={team2} name={user.firstName} email="mail@me.com!" />
    })
  };
```

The suggested change with map results in an "Unexpected token, expected "," ".

Comment: Why are you pushing strings?

Comment: Square bracket notation could be used to access property - `accessor`. For e.g ```<User image={team2} name={user[accessor]} email="mail@me.com! />```

Comment: Perhaps I am confused but what is users here: `rows:  users.map((user)`

Comment: users is my array, defined earlier in the code

Comment: I believe your error is due to the missing `)` on the second to last line

Answer (score 0):

DO not push strings in the rows array

```js
let rows=[]

users.map((user)=>{
    rows.push({
        name: <User image={team2} name={user.firstName} email="mail@me.com! />
    })
})
```

Comment: Ok but what is the variable row? I only have the rows array..

Comment: You can change the variable to rows

Comment: So i should use it like this?    
rows: [
      users.map((user) => {
        rows.push({
          name: <User image={team2} name={user.firstName} email="mail@me.com" />,
        });
      }),
    ],


because this leads to an "Can't find variable: rows" error

Comment: No you cannot use it like this , please go through the basics of javascript

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the expected result because `forEach` doesn't return anything, and you're not doing anything with the data inside your loop.

The functional approach would be to use `map` so it returns an array like below

```
{
  rows: users.map((user) => ({
    name: <User image={team2} name={user.firstName} email="mail@me.com!" />
  }))
}
```

The map function returns an array, so you don't need to worry about managing the array yourself.